# Azure Mobile Service deployed to Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

Because of the limited region availability of deploying Azure Mobile Services, I am investigating deploying the service to Azure Websites. I can deploy the service to a website using the deployment profile easy enough and everything seems to work.

I was just wondering if anyone has had any experience in doing so? Limitations compared to the official Mobile Service hosted deployment? And any specific required changes to typical code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having implemented this and using it for the past few months, these are the results I found.

Minimal changes are needed except manually specifying config values as app settings vs the mobile services configuration. I am using Azure AD authentication and the required keys to be configured in Azure websites app settings were

- MS_MobileServiceName
- MS_MobileServiceDomainSuffix
- MS_MasterKey
- MS_ApplicationKey
- MS_AadClientId
- MS_AadTenants
- MS_AadAudience

I wrote about the changes here https://pontifex.azurewebsites.net/azure-mobile-services-hosted-in-azure-websites/